# Selenium python: InvalidSessionIdException when running multiple tests

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Each test run is successful but it fails when I run them in one go.

test_01.py

```
from testutil import *

driver = testutil.driver

class ClassOne(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_find_title(self):
        testutil.setup() 
        assert 'Welcome' in driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='title001']").text   
        testutil.teardown()
```

test_02.py

```
from testutil import *

driver = testutil.driver
home_url='https://url/CTA/'
    
class ClassTwo(unittest.TestCase):        
    def test_click_button(self):    
        testutil.setup()            
        driver.get(home_url)
        create_btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#quick-create').click()
        assert WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='create_item']"))           
        testutil.teardown()
```

testutil.py

```
class testutil:
    myun = 'aaa'
    mypw = 'bbb'
    base_url="https://url/login.action"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    
    @classmethod
    def setup(self):        
        driver = self.driver    
        driver.get(self.base_url)        
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='username']")
        password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='password']")
        username.send_keys(self.myun)
        password.send_keys(self.mypw)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='loginButton']").submit()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        assert 'Dashboard' in driver.title

    @classmethod
    def teardown(self):
        self.driver.get('https://url/login.action?logout=true')
        self.driver.close()
```

I tried removing self.driver.close() but then the setup function failed in the second test.

command:

> python -m unittest discover -s 'c:\selenium\test' -p 'test_*py'

Error message:

> ERROR: test_create_and_delete_space (test.TestSpace)
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\selenium\test\test_01.py",
> line 23, in test_find_title   testutil.setup()   File
> "c:\selenium\test\testutil.py", line 23, in setup
> driver.get(self.base_url)   File
> "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 449, in get  self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})   File
> "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 440, in execute  self.error_handler.check_response(response)
> File
> "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 245, in check_response   raise exception_class(message, screen,
> stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException:
> Message: invalid session id Stacktrace: Backtrace:        GetHandleVerifier
> [0x009F8893+48451]        (No symbol) [0x0098B8A1]        (No symbol)
> [0x00894F20]      (No symbol) [0x008B7A42]        (No symbol) [0x008B8F2D]
> GetHandleVerifier [0x00C58E3A+2540266]      GetHandleVerifier
> [0x00C98959+2801161]      GetHandleVerifier [0x00C9295C+2776588]
> GetHandleVerifier [0x00A82280+612144]       (No symbol) [0x00994F6C]
> (No symbol) [0x009911D8]        (No symbol) [0x009912BB]        (No symbol)
> [0x00984857]      BaseThreadInitThunk [0x755100C9+25]
> RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77207B4E+286]
> RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77207B1E+238]